Insulate Enclosed Tub
Imagine a clawfoot that just had a box built around it. Problem is that box is not insulated so when it's cold out, the heat goes out of the water really quickly.
We did a test drill on top, each to open a hole into this chamber, but filling the whole chamber with close cell foam is not going to happen.
Any other ideas? Seems like I would have to take the whole top off. Remove the tub, spray close cell foam on the outside of it, and maybe on the inside of the wall (exterior), then put it back and redo the top?

Its hard to know without pictures or diagrams.  Why wont the foam happen?

Fill the box with blown-in cellulose or fiberglass if you don't want to fill it with foam (presumably due to the expense, but you don't say why, as the prior comment notes.) Or pop the top off and stuff it with rockwool batts, rigid foam sheets, old styrofoam packing peanuts, etc...
